# managing server application

Tags: python, database, flask

I have a server which runs flask with python.

Now I want to make an application which can do various tasks like uploading files, updating redis database and various other things.

Now ofcourse this could be done using html pages but since the operation could involve lots of files realtime input of data and other things it might be better to make an application and manage the server from that point rather than webpages.

do you suggest using webpages anyway or would you make an application for it?

and if I make an application should I use http or not?

sorry if this is a uninformed question but I would like to learn the best methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It allows you to run various commands related to your flask application easily. It also allows you to easily add your own commands to it. This way you will be able to keep your administrative code still within the Flask app, but not necessarily have it accessible via a web page.